# Write a basis for a hyperplane in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Write a basis for a hyper plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

A hyper plane in $R^3$ is,

$$\overrightarrow{x} = c_1<1, 0, 0> + c_2<0, 1 , 0>, c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$

So I did some calculations with span and got that the the basis would be

$A = \{<1, 0 ,0>, <0, 1, 0> \}$

But that is literally almost the exact same thing?

Comment: It is expected to be the same thing, looking at the way it is defined. But then, the question seems too easy, so I'm wondering if you've missed some detail.

Answer (score 0):

The hyperplane is the set

$H=\{c_1<1, 0, 0> + c_2<0, 1 , 0>: c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

$H $ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3$. A basis of $H$ is given by $A = \{<1, 0 ,0>, <0, 1, 0> \}$, hence

$$H= span(A).$$